# WooCommerce Orders Query

Tags: woocommerce

Need a query where I can get products_ids from orders with the condition that such order must contain a specific **product_id**.

With this, what I want to get is other products bought by other users when chosen a specific product.

This is the query I'm working now:

```
    $orders = new WP_Query(
            array(
                    'post_type' => array('shop_order'),
                    'post_status'   => array('wc-completed', 'wc-pending')
                )
    );
```

but do not know how to insert the conditionals.